# mysql and php : Data extraction

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck trying to figure out a solution for the problem below.
It's quite complicated. So stay with me.

I retrieve a field from the `user` table which has his friends' user ids in the form of CSV
(3,4,5,6,7)

There is another table called `transaction` which looks something like this

```
tid    user1   user2   type_of_trade
1       3        4      barter
2       5        6      share
3       6        7      bargain 
4       4        3      barter
5       3        7      share
```

Now I need to display the transactions of my friends.

So I split the CSV, put them in an array and for each friend I'm running the query

```
friends = explode(",","3,4,5,6,7");

for($i=0;$i<=count(friends);$i++)
{
// I execute this--SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE user1 = friends[$i] or user2 = friends[$i]
}
```

Now the same happens for 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7

When the query executes for `4`, the same result comes and hence I'm getting duplicates.
I've tried everything. But I'm unable to figure this out.

Can someone please suggest a better solution or can this itself be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, do *not* `explode` it.

```
SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE user1 IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) OR user2 IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: My understanding is that gnanesh wants *all* transactions even if a pair of friends did multiple transactions.  Whats more there is a supposedly distinguishing tid column so they’ll always be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You should myke use of the [mysql IN() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). This will guarantee unique results.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user1 IN (3,4,5,6,7) OR user2 IN (3,4,5,6,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `IN` comparison:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM transaction
WHERE user1 IN (3,4,5,6,7) OR user2 IN (3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the database design at all, I would recommend using a Many to Many relationship for your users friends.

This will allow you to store a list of a users friends without needing to parse the CSV.

An implementation of this in PHP & mysql is here; [tonymarston.net](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html), was just the first result for google: 'mysql many to many'.